# Ejecutar funcion cuando se renderice un elemento html - Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, events, primevue

Estoy usando un Carousel de `primevue` y no tengo un control completo sobre los eventos que ocurren al moverme por el contenido (es un componente muy complejo), y cuando lo llamo lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
<Carousel :value="imagenes">
    <template #item="slotProps">
      <div class="contenedor">
        <img
          v-if="propMarker == 1"
          class="foto-propiedad"
          :src="slotProps.data.original"
          :class="{ ultima: slotProps.data == imagenes[4] }"
        />
        <img
          v-else
          class="foto-propiedad"
          :src="slotProps.data.thumb"
          :class="{ ultima: slotProps.data == imagenes[4] }"
        />
        <div
          v-if="slotProps.data == imagenes[4]"
          class="overlay"
        >
          <div class="content-overlay ultima"
          @click="activarVisible">
            Mostrar {{ cantidad - 5 }} fotos más
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </Carousel>
```

Como pueden ver, hay un `v-if="slotProps.data == imagenes[4]"` que muestra un elemento en particular.
Quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de que, cuando se renderiza

```
        <div
          v-if="slotProps.data == imagenes[4]"
          class="overlay"
        >
          <div class="content-overlay ultima"
          @click="activarVisible">
            Mostrar {{ cantidad - 5 }} fotos más
          </div>
        </div>
```

Se ejecute una función (tengo que capturar un elemento externo con jquery y aplicarle una clase css), sin necesidad de hacer `@click` o cualquier evento por el estilo? Quisiera que la funcion se ejecute cuando el elemento se muestra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que se ejecuten funciones en componentes puedes usar v-on sin llamar luego a ningún evento y luego definir tu función en los métodos

```
<my-element v-on="myFunction()"></my-element>
```

y luego en el script

```
methods: {
    myFunction = function () {
        // función que se ejecuta automáticamente
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva